# Correct Use of Ruby Proc

Tags: ruby, proc

I'd like to know if there's a way to define the proc at the top of this method elsewhere and still retain the proc's ability to return from the scope of a method.

```
  def add_user_to_team(user_id, team_id)

    v = Proc.new do |t|
      return t if t.error
      t
    end

    User.transaction do

      user = v.call(
        validate_user_exists(user_id)).obj

      team = v.call(
        validate_team_exists(team_id)).obj

      ...lots of other validations...

      result(true, nil, team_user)
    end

  end
```

I'd like to be able to define this proc in a module that we could include elsewhere.  But, when I have a method return the proc, i get a LocalJumpError with the return statement.

For example, I'd like to do

```
def validate
  Proc.new do |t|
    return t if t.error
    t
  end
end
```

And refine the the original code to do

```
  def add_user_to_team(user_id, team_id)

    User.transaction do

      user = validate.call(
        validate_user_exists(user_id)).obj

      team = validate.call(
        validate_team_exists(team_id)).obj

      ...lots of other validations...

      result(true, nil, team_user)
    end

  end
```

I'm also open to any other suggestions for how to consolidate this error-checking logic which

1. bails out if the scoped method if a validation fails
2. returns the object if no error and continues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use `throw`/`catch` to prematurely exit the method:

```
module ValidationHelpers
  def check t
    throw :fail, t if t.error
    t
  end
end
```

And to use it in your validation method:

```
def add_user_to_team(user_id, team_id)
  catch(:fail) do
    User.transaction do
      user = check(validate_user_exists(user_id)).obj
      team = check(validate_team_exists(team_id)).obj
      # ...lots of other validations...
      result(true, nil, team_user)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hm, this is a pretty nice solution.  My first time interacting with `catch`.  Can you expand this example to show how I'd deal with the return value from `:fail`?

Comment: Or does `catch(:fail)` return the result from `check`?

Comment: `catch(:fail)` will return the second argument to `throw :fail`, in this case `t`: http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/07/12/throw-catch-raise-rescue-im-so-confused/

Comment: Ha, we found the same blog.  Seems canonical.  Thanks, I implemented this and works nicely.  I like how throw does not incur overhead.